# PHP header location to current page

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, header

I have a static HTML page that uses a simple contact form. As the user clicks the send button it uses a .php page to send the data. I've tested this and it works fine, the issue I have is how to just keep the user on that html page once they have sent their message. I don't want a redirect at all (if it's possible, i'd like to be able to just close the modal the contact form is in and return to what ever page they were just on - this contact form is on multiple pages).

What I have: `header('Location: index.html');` redirects fine but I'd have to create a php contact script page for every single page using this.

What I've tried: `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` and `header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

JavaScript: `onclick="window.location.reload(true)"` did nothing.

**I've gotten this to work the way I wanted by using AJAX. This was all brand new to me so I thank you very much for all you who helped me out. Even going through the answers that didn't do what I wanted in the end taught me some new stuff - and that's a good thing in my book. Appreciate your time people :)

If you want to see it in action - check it out on my test page : http://www.novasev.com/NST/about.html : it's the "Get in Touch" button on the bottom panel.

Comment: So is AJAX out of the question?

Comment: I've never used AJAX before so I'm completely unsure. I guess I should have included a part asking what the best way to do this is. I figured it would be with a simple PHP script but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should use jQuery and submit your contact form using Ajax. By using Ajax you will send the contact form in the background and the user will not see page refresh, that is: the modal window will remain and you may close it using javascript code.

Here's a simple example that I hope will help you on the right track. To catch potential errors from your contact.php script, check out the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact").submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
           alert("Thanks for contacting us!");
         }
      })
      // Prevent that page reloads
      return false;
    })
  })
</script>

<form id="contact">
   <input type="text" name="name" /> 
   <input type="text" name="msg" /> 
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Here's the part that I don't understand in using this - as I've seen it else where before. Where/how do I direct the message to a specific email and/or inbox? Going to give this a try - it's probably time I start learning things like this - gotta break it before I fix it though lol. Thanks for your help. I will take this route and hopefully come up with something useful.

Comment: If you want to send what's been submitted in the form, then you will have to have write that code in `contact.php` (your server). That is the file that will receive the data that was submitted. Check the `$_POST` variable. Once you got that, you send email by using PHP's [mail-function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). That's requires a proper configurarion; sometimes it is easier to use a service like MailGun. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, just figured that part out - just now trying to get it so that when the message is sent, it will stick on the same html page instead of going to the php page.

Comment: Ok sorry my bad. I updated the code with a `return false` statement that cancels the "reload-page-submission". You should get a alert-message; that is a pop-up saying "Thanks for contacting us!".

Comment: Frick - i knew it was going to be something kinda simple. I'm totally new to these areas - small but powerful uses here. I now need to learn how to use something other then a js alert box (I've read that they can be harmful in deployment). Any links you might know off the top of your head for this?

I have the contact form within a modal window, the modal window has a css/js code to close it but I can't figure out how to add that within the js to replace the alert. I'll be playing with that now - thanks for the help you're awesome.

Comment: Check out Twitter's Bootstrap - it a css and JS framework with, for exaample alert widgets. If you're planing on doing PHP for a long time I would start looking at [PHP frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com). They are scary from the start, but they come with lots of guides and basically they will help you under stand how CSS, JS, HTML, PHP come together. I like the Yii-framework - but that's also the only one I have used :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete shot in the dark.

This will infinitely redirect to itself forever and cause the browser to error.

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Try this

```
if(!isset($_GET['r']))
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?r=1');
```

This will redirect but with a parameter, this `r` parameter can then be checked to ensure the redirect does not occur again and again.

Comment: That just gives me parse error once I hit the send button - exactly on the line for the if statement. Is it possible to include the php script inside my html page? Just at the bottom below the footer or body tag like some JS scripts are?

Comment: That did fix the parse error, but still lands me on the contact.php page. The form is on the about.html page, it's action directs it to the contact.php page - where I in turn want it to redirect back to the about.html page. This contact button will be used on multiple pages otherwise I'd just have it directed easily using the location param. Maybe that clears things up a bit. I'm more then willing to learn something new too.

Comment: Your .html file will not exec PHP - could that be a contributing factor? If you want to redirect to a specific page just do `header('Location: /contact.php?r=1');`

Comment: Hmmm, that still didn't work. It does send the email but doesn't return to the original page. Sorry, i'm sure I'm frustrating you lol. I may just try and go with the AJAX script if I can figure out how to set that up.

Comment: Another option for me would be to just have no redirect at all. Anytime I try to take that portion out (and I've searched for this fix so much) it just gives me a parse error. Is there a specific line of code to do nothing but send up a success message? Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score -1):

Use an AJAX call with POST to send the data on a submit to the url, if possible. You would by pass the redirect this way.